# Serve static websites with Rails based on user session

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to user route constraints from Rails 3 / 4 to server complete websites based on user login (user centric routing)? I was roughly thinking about putting different static websites in sub-directorys in the app and make them accessible for users under the main root (secured by login).

If no user is logged in, a simple login mask is used to identify the user, e.g. with devise. I was thinking to simplify the staging deployment for static pages, e.g. generated with middleman. It would be much better to have a simple capistrano task for deploying into a rails app, instead of creating a subdomain, ftp upload etc.

The reason for mounting static pages under / is, that most static site generators expect the page to be under /, and i'd like to avoid problems with absolute/relative paths in the assets.

To be more specific:

*case 1)* user is not logged in -> any route asks for auth

*case 2)* user is logged in, static content is served from /app/sites/site1 ( mounted at "/" )

*case 3)* another user is logged in, static content is served from /app/sites/site2 ( mounted at "/" )

the site served depends on users profile.

Comment: Please add a bit more information. A concrete example would be great. There are several ways of solving this.

Comment: I'm wondering if Rails is overkill for this, perhaps you should consider something like Sinatra: http://www.sinatrarb.com/

Comment: Could you clarify this question?

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?

Answer (score 0):

To anwer my own question: Yes it is possible.

In my case, Rails is not overkill. I have a seamless integration with our Rails-based project management system. I'm mounting a [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/)-App as a web server, using a different public url based on user session. The session is generated via unique token, so that a user can view different static projects right after another.

routes.rb:

```
constraints(:subdomain => /preview/) do
    mount SinatraWrapper => "/"
end
```

Note: i'm using constrains here, to check subdomain. Every static preview is redirected to the same app, under a different subdomain.

Sinatra Wrapper:

```
# a super-trivial Sinatra-based webserver
# for static content
require 'sinatra/base'

class SinatraWrapper < Sinatra::Base
  before '/*' do
    SinatraWrapper.set_site(session[:site])
  end

  def self.set_site(site)
    rootPath = File.expand_path("#{Rails.root}/sites/#{site}/")
    set :public_folder, "#{rootPath}/current/build/"
  end

  configure do
    set :static, true
    set :static_cache_control, [:public, :no_store, :no_cache, :must_revalidate, :max_age => 0, :expires => "Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT"]
  end

  set_site("default")

  # route to starting page (index.html)
  get "/" do
    redirect "/index.html"
  end

  # route to custom error page (404.html)
  not_found do
    redirect "/404.html"
  end

end
```

Note: i'm deploying updates from static projects via capistrano right into the rails app. The build is performed remote via [Middleman](http://middlemanapp.com/) ( we *could* use any other static site generator here). Another instance checks our git repositories for updates in the "preview"-branch and run tests on it. After passing all tests, a build is performed and deployed automatically.

Here is the tricky bit, using different behaviour for two different subdomains, but same session:

```
# static_pages_controller.rb:

def preview

    if request.subdomain == "preview" or Rails.env.development? # local dev: no subdomains
      @static_page = StaticPage.find(params[:id])
      session[:site] = @static_page.slug || "default" # using a sha-slug for every static project
      redirect_to "/" # redirect to root. we have a valid session now.
    else
      # we are NOT on the preview subdomain, so we need to redirect to proper subdomain
      @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
      @static_page = StaticPage.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to preview_url(project_id: @project.id, id: @static_page.id, token: @static_page.slug).sub("plattform", "preview")
    end
end
```

Note: I have projects with many many static pages. We have a preview action for every static page from the plattform. If you hit the preview action with a link from the plattform, you are redirected to the preview subdomain and your session is set. Our authentication allows us to

- send anonymous links with authentication tokens (SHA-Slugs) to a customer
- and authenticate via database

We use this system for half a year now and are very satisfied! The customer can see a preview right away. Until now, we have not encountered any serious problems, except that the caching headers must be set correctly to ensure that new content is loaded every time you reload the page. This slows down the experience, but we can always argument, that this is a preview. To be honest, most customers do not recognize the load times.

Anyway, i am not 100% sure if my implementation for "crashing" the cache is the perfect solution. Any hint would be very much appreciated. I only have problems in Chrome and Safari (very rare), where you need to reload the page several times until new content is shown.

Another interesting question is security. I *think* it is relatively safe. But i'm no security expert. Any concerns?

We use this platform only internally. No product, so we do not handle errors very gentle.